# Set attribute values while creating an ArcGIS Server feature in esri-leaflet?

Tags: editing, feature-layer, esri-leaflet

The Esri-Leaflet sample map [Editing feature layers](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/editable.html) shows how the *geometry* of an ArcGIS Server feature layer can be created in Leaflet, by digitising a new polygon which is inserted into the feature layer.

Is it possible to set the *attributes* of the newly created feature?

This code inserts the new feature into the feature layer: `pedestrianDistricts.addFeature(e.layer.toGeoJSON())`

Examining the value of `e.layer.toGeoJSON()` in the debugger I can see that there are no `properties` (ie attributes) on the editable layer. Is it possible to pass the desired attributes while creating the geometry, during the `addFeature`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, I spent ages on this problem then figured out the answer immediately after posting the question on GIS SE.

One simple solution is to first convert the layer to GeoJSON, amend this by adding the required value, then continue with the `addFeature` using the amended GeoJSON:

`map.on('editable:drawing:commit', function (e) {
  var layerJSON = e.layer.toGeoJSON();
  layerJSON.properties['PEDDISTRIC'] = 'blah';
  pedestrianDistricts.addFeature(layerJSON);
});`

Comment: nice. see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834401/edit-feature-attributes-in-leaflet and this 'secret' sample: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/editing.html

Comment: @JohnGravois thanks, the secret sample looks perfect for my purposes